# How do I remove the search bar for my SharePoint pages

Tags: 2007, search

Is there a way to hide (or remove) the search bar located above the 'Site Action' link and below the 'Welcome {User name}' for SharePoint 2007 web pages?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options:

- Remove the Delegate control SmallSearchInutBox from the master page
- The "right" way: create/activate a feature with an empty Control element with that ID and a Sequence below 25.

You can find a feature like this at [Remove the Search Box from SharePoint Sites](http://www.theblackknightsings.com/RemoveTheSearchBoxFromSharePointSites.aspx)

Comment: +1 for Delegate control - it's the way to go.

Comment: Are there other ways beside editing the master page as I still want some of my site to have search bar and plus I cannot access the master page due to restriction set by system administrator.

Comment: That's the second option specified. The feature at the link has WebApplication scope, but that can be changed to as finegrained as you want.

Comment: then you can try the solution of hiding the control by setting/overriding the CSS class. You can add a content editor webpart and add the CSS in to the webpart, this WP can be added only in those pages where you want to hide the search control.

Answer (score 1):

All the controls and styling for the search bar will be in your master page, whichever one you are using. You can select the control and add a display:hidden css tag to the div and this will hide the control.

This method means the code for the search bar will be compiled so the page is not necessarily more lightweight, all it does is hide the control. If you actually want to remove the control completely, be careful of that because you may have trouble getting it back!

Tal

Comment: Please tell me more about how to select the control and add a display:hidden css tag.

Answer (score 0):

This is added in the master page, hence removing the delegate control present in the master page should sove your problem.